# Mysql query with '=' is much slower than 'LIKE'

Tags: mysql

I am currently running into an issue where, when I use a "LIKE" in my query I get the result in 2 seconds. But when I use the '=' instead, it takes around 1 minute for the result to show up.
The following is my query:

- QUERY1

The following query takes 2 seconds:

```
`select distinct p.Name from Timeset s 
join table1 f on (f.id = s.id) 
join table2 p on (p.source=f.table_name) 
join table3 d on (d.Name = p.Name) WHERE 
 s.Active = 'Y' AND **p.sourcefrom like '%sometable%'`
```

- QUERY2

The same query replacing the 'like' by '=' takes 1 minute:

```
select distinct p.Name from Timeset s 
join table1 f on (f.id = s.id) 
join table2 p on (p.source=f.table_name) 
join table3 d on (d.Name = p.Name) WHERE 
 s.Active = 'Y' AND **p.sourcefrom = 'sometable'
```

I am really puzzled because I know that 'LIKE' is usually slower (than '=') since mysql need to look for different possibilities. But I am sure why in my case, "=" is slower with such a substantial difference.

thank you kindly for the help in advance,

regards,

Comment: Both queries are identical. Please edit your question.

Comment: possibly due to the query plan... is there a mysql equivalent to update statistics?

Comment: Index on `table2.sourcefrom`?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `=` MySQL is probably using a different index compared to when you use `LIKE`. Check the output from the two execution plans and see what the differnce is. Then you can FORCE the use of the better performing index. Might be worth running `ANALYZE TABLE` for each of the tables involved.